# Restrict Access to the User Profile

Tags: users, user-roles, dashboard, profiles, user-access

What I want is, give different Roles different kind of access to the user profile. For example, I want to show the section "Name" but not the section "Contact information".
From other sections I just want to remove a select box and a textfield, but not everything.
Also the Yoast SEO configuration and the mailchimp list selection I dont want to show to the user.

How can I remove/hide those things?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `current_user_can( $capability )`. Where [$capabilty](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) applies.

For example:

```
If ( current_user_can( 'update_plugins' ){
//do some update plugin stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. I know that function. But this doesn't allow me to specify different fields in the user profile to be shown or not to different roles.

Comment: That is not what you asked. What user profile? Where is the code you have attempted?

Comment: The user profile in the backend. When a user logs in and clicks on the page "Your profile" in wp-admin.
There are different sections like "Name", "Contact information", "About you" etc. I want to remove certain sections for different roles. For example, users with Role A should see "Name" but should not see others. Users with Role B should see "Contact information" and "About" but not "Name".